# 2.75 mm SSD in HDD case?

Tags: ssd, msata

I have [this SSD](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00PXXUAB8)

It appears to have a 2.75 mm height.

I want to buy a mSata USB case to turn it into an external drive, but I cannot find a case that mentions these dimensions. Will this work with any mSata case, even one for 7.5mm HDD?

Comment: If its expecting a 7.5mm HDD then it will be to small.

Comment: These dimensions refer to the case, not the connectors, right? Will I not be able to plug the SSD in the case? Will it just not be ideal because there will be wiggle room, or will it not work at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this on [Amazon for $12.99](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00LRZPNHM) as of 3/31/2015. As you can see below, mSATA will fit inside the case. After that, it is a matter of preference in terms of color, style, size, features, etc.

mSATA shouldn't be 7.5mm drive. If you're referring to 2.5" inch SSD, then you need a different case.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

mSATA is mSATA, so it'll work, but the drive will move around in the case.

You can pad it with non conductive material but you also need to consider ventilation.

Comment: mSATA drives are held in with two screws through the end of the board. It won't move.

Answer (score -1):

You will need an MSATA specific case as these are traditionally used internally.  I found;

> VisionTek mSATA Mini USB 3.0 SSD    Enclosure - 900696

At walmart,

> http://mobile.walmart.com/ip/38106749?wmlspartner=wlpa&adid=22222222228026042320&wl0=&wl1=g&wl2=m&wl3=56454856089&wl4=&wl5=pla&wl6=89135305209&veh=sem

For 35 USD that should suit your needs.